# Add New Custom UIFontTextStyle in Xcode Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

[image]

I want to add my own font text style in interface builder (just below Title 3 text style) so I don't have to redefine it every time.

I use the same text style, if it's possible, how? thanks

**Edit:**
I have 10 styles that I use in my design and it's "Avenir Next" font not some external custom font

Comment: Do you have .ttf or .otf file of the font style you want to use?

Comment: no, I just want to use some kind of UIFontTextStylesMyOwnStyle (Avenir Next font and I have 10 styles for my app) because I use it a lot in my design. Just want to make my work a little bit easy when setting UI font in interface builder

Comment: If your font style is "Avenir Next" then it is already available as custom font in Interface Builder.

Comment: I think I need to rewrite my question. I have 10 styles, instead of choosing manually (font name, font type, and size) every time I want to set some styles, it will be easier if I can have my own custom styles just like Body, callout, footnote, etc so I just set one value instead of three (and I dont have to remember its combination)